# factory class that prevents direct instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

How to create a factory class that prevents direct instantiation of a class ?

say, i have class Comment that should only be instantiated from a class CommentFactory.
I don't want Comment to be able to be instantiated directly.

I figured I could do this :

```
  public partial class Comment
  {
    private Comment(){}
    public Comment CreateComment(User user,string str)
    {
       Comment cmt=new Comment();
       user.AddComment(cmt);
       cmt.User=user;
       return cmt;       
    }
  }
```

is this code clean ?

now, the problem i'm facing is that the Comment is a partial class with partial implementation done by Linq to SQL. and Linq to SQL creates a public constructor of this class, so how can i circumvent this ? is there any 'trick' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking can be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932059/limiting-access-to-a-public-setter-to-specific-objects-c). It's not exactly the same, but the solutions will be almost identical.

I figure there are at least 3 tricks to solve your question, so it'll add more flexibility for you.

Answer (score 0):

If Comment and CommentFactory are in the same assembly, making all constructors of Comment internal will prevent any code outside of the assembly from creating instances of Comment.

Comment: yeah, the code i don't want to access the Comment constructor is located in the same assembly. to create a different assembly should i create a new dll project ?

Comment: yes, if you create a new dll project, any code in that project would not be able to create Comment instances as long as Comment's constructors are `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the constructor `internal` to an assembly that CommentFactory resides in and then have consumers access the CommentFactory class. I'm not sure how else to "enforce" it.